# How many changes does a maze require until the destination becomes reachable?

Tags: algorithm

I came across this interview question. The first part is as follows:

> You are given matrix containing letters 'U', 'D', 'L', 'R' and 'X'. 'U' allow you to move up, 'L' allows to move left, etc. 'X' is the
>   destination. Check if it is possible to reach the destination from the
>   top left corner.

This part is easily done with DFS. I struggle with the second part though:

> How many edits (e.g. change 'U' -> 'L') you need to make in order to
>   reach X

I assume that it can be done with a modified BFS counting the number of times we went against specified direction. Could someone give a hint?

Comment: Is it legit for an element in the matrix to contain more than one letters? Is it legit after the edit?

Comment: no. the given matrix is allowed to have only one character in a cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix represents a directed graph: the nodes are locations in the matrix, and the (directed) edges are represented by the letter in the node.

Then, there's a path from the top-left corner to X if there's a path in the graph from the top-left corner to X. You can determine this by using Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. (You can also use DFS, but we'll need Dijkstra in the second part anyway).

To determine the smallest number of edits to make a path possible, one can turn the matrix into a weighted, directed graph. Between any two adjacent nodes `a` and `b`, add a weighted edge between `a` and `b` with weight `0` if `a` already contains the direction of `b`, and weight `1` otherwise. The edge of weight `0` represents following the direction already in the matrix, and the edge of weight `1` represents editing the node.

Then, use Dijkstra's algorithm find the lowest-weight path from the top-left corner to `X` in this graph. The weight of this shortest path is the number of edits needed.

Comment: I can't decide if I like this approach. I like the recognition that this is a special case of a general problem whose well-known solutions can be applied; but on the other hand, those well-known general solutions are more complex than is needed for this case.

Comment: @ruakh Do you think your solution is significantly easier to implement than Dijkstra's algorithm? It seems about the same to me.

Comment: I think so, yes, but maybe I'm biased. :-P (My solution also has slightly better asymptotic complexity, though that's unlikely to make a difference in realistic cases.)

Comment: for me it was easier to implement good old dijkstra than to a custom solution from @ruakh. took me about 20 minutes. You don't need to build a graph from the matrix, you can just use matrix itself, since you know who is connected to whom.

Comment: The solution from @ruakh is good, and shouldn't be more difficult to implement. I think my solution may be in practice easier because probably you've implemented Dijkstra before. But ruakh's solution has, as ruakh points out, got better time complexity -- it's O(V) rather than this which is O(V log V).

Comment: one thing is not clear to me in ruakh's solution. Let's say we've discovered cells reachable from (0,0) and 'X' is not among those. Now we need to choose the next cell and assign it a distance 1. How do we choose this next cell? Let's say we choose any cell from those that we already discovered (name it A) and choose some neighbor of it (name it B). We then discover reachable cells from B, they will all have distance 1. How do we choose the next cell? We don't want to choose A's neighbor B again and discover that it already has distance. We want to keep track of valid candidates somehow.

Answer (score 4):

In essence, you want to compute what might be called the "edit distance" from the top left corner to each element of the matrix (and in particular, to the element marked `X`), by which I mean the number of edits you'd have to make in the matrix in order to be able to reach a given element from the top left corner.

To do this, you can start by finding all the elements where the "edit distance" is zero, meaning, the top-left corner and all elements that are already reachable from it. (You mention that you can use depth-first search for this, but it's not even really a "search", since each element tells you exactly which element comes after it. So there's just a single path from the top left corner, that either ends at `X`, ends by "walking off" an edge, or gets into a cycle.)

You can then use *breadth*-first search, starting from the set of elements you just found. For any given *d*, the elements with edit distance = *d* + 1 are all the elements that:

- don't have edit distance ≤ *d*;
- and either:

  - are neighbors of an element with edit distance = *d*
  - or are reachable from such a neighbor

You can stop as soon as you've computed the edit distance of the square marked `X`.

This approach visits each element at most once, so if the matrix has *N* elements, this approach is in *O*(*N*) time and space.

Comment: I think it will work. I just cannot imagine implementing it in 30 minutes. It's seems like a combination of BFS (we go layer by layer) and DFS (after adding element with d+1 distance we have to explore its reachable elements).

Comment: @damluar: The DFS can just be a loop -- no stack or recursion or whatnot is needed -- since no element has outdegree greater than one. It will populate the `edit_distance` table. The BFS can also just be a loop that keeps a `to_process` queue of elements where we've already set `edit_distance` but haven't yet searched for neighbors. But yeah, 30 minutes is pretty tight.

Comment: I agree with the algorithm; but time and space complexity is o(n^2) like the matrix size

Comment: @Dolev: The OP did not indicate that this is a square matrix, so rather than introducing separate variables *n* and *m* for the number of rows and number of columns, I thought it would be simpler to just introduce *N* for the total number of elements. I take it you disagree?

Comment: If N is the size of the matrix I agree. But you wrote array in the answer that I misinterpreted. +1

Comment: @Dolev: Ah, I see. I've now changed "array" to "matrix" for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one path, so iterate it from the beginning and mark every square you visit as "reachable from start". The go to the end and do the same thing, running backwards. Because you are running backwards,, there are potentially many paths (an UP and a DOWN could both lead into the same square). Anyway, mark those square as "end reachable from". If the first set contains a square adjacent to the second set, you need one edit. Otherwise you have to mark the separating squares, and do a distance transform, followed by a feature transform (see my binary image library). The "narrowest neck" has to be edited to drive a path from set one to set two).